# How to know the git username and email saved during configuration?

Tags: git, git-config

While configuring `git` I ran these two commands:

```
git config --global user.name "My Name"

git config --global user.email "myemail@example.com"
```

However, I doubt whether I made a typo or not. So, is there any command to know the **name** and **email** which `git` saved during configuration? Obviously, I can know that using the `git log` command by looking at the commit history. But for that I have to make commits, right? Can I know that with the help of command line?

Comment: Do you change your OS or something like that?

Comment: Yes, sometimes I format my system to try out a different OS.

Comment: git config --list

Answer (score 839, accepted):

The command [`git config --list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---list) will list the settings. There you should also find `user.name` and `user.email`.

Comment: This command only shows the global settings not the one applicable for the repository you're currently in. E.g. overwriting the user.email in the repository will still show the `git config --global user.email` setting when using `git config --list`.

Comment: @manuelwaldner Then what's the correct way to see `user.name` for the repository we're currently in?

Comment: @starriet just use `git config user.name` in this case, see the answer of @jebin-philipose below.

Answer (score 264):

Considering what [@Robert said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46941431), I tried to play around with the `config` command and it seems that there is a direct way to know both the name and email.

To know the username, type:

```
git config user.name
```

To know the email, type:

```
git config user.email
```

These two output just the name and email respectively and one doesn't need to look through the whole list. Comes in handy.

Comment: This not only shows the stuff we want to see, but it shows the _local_ config, _not_ global config. As @manuelwaldner mentioned in another comment.

Answer (score 158):

**Inside your git repository directory**, run `git config user.name`.

> Why is running this command within your git repo directory important?

If you are outside of a git repository, `git config user.name` gives you the value of `user.name` at **global** level. When you make a commit, the associated user name is read at **local** level.

Although unlikely, let's say `user.name` is defined as `foo` at **global** level, but `bar` at **local** level. Then, when you run `git config user.name` outside of the git repo directory, it gives `bar`. However, when you really commits something, the associated value is `foo`.

---

> ## Git config variables can be stored in 3 different levels. Each level overrides values in the previous level.

**1. System level (applied to every user on the system and all their repositories)**

- to view, `git config --list --system` (may need `sudo`)
- to set, `git config --system color.ui true`
- to edit system config file, `git config --edit --system`

**2. Global level (values specific personally to you, the user. )**

- to view, `git config --list --global`
- to set, `git config --global user.name xyz`
- to edit global config file, `git config --edit --global`

**3. Repository level (specific to that single repository)**

- to view, `git config --list --local`
- to set, `git config --local core.ignorecase true` (`--local` optional)
- to edit repository config file, `git config --edit --local` (`--local` optional)

> ## How to view **all** settings?

- Run `git config --list`, showing **system**, **global**, and (if inside a repository) **local** configs
- Run `git config --list --show-origin`, also shows the origin file of each config item

> ## How to read one particular config?

- Run `git config user.name` to get `user.name`, for example.
- You may also specify options `--system`, `--global`, `--local` to read that value at a particular level.

---

Reference: [1.6 Getting Started - First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)

Comment: @sam I'm inside the local repo, set the username and email. But git push is still using global name. Why is that?

Comment: This is a more complete answer as it is critical in many scenarios (e.g. having multiple users for different repos) to understand the separation between global and local configurations

Answer (score 75):

**List all variables set in the config file, along with their values.**

```
git config --list
```

***If you are new to git then use the following commands to set a user name and email address.***

**Set user name**

```
git config --global user.name "your Name"
```

**Set user email**

```
git config --global user.email "your_email@example.com"
```

**Check user name**

```
git config user.name
```

**Check user email**

```
git config user.email
```

Answer (score 47):

> If you want to check or set the user name and email you can use the below
>   command

**Check user name**

```
git config user.name
```

**Set user name**

```
git config user.name "your_name"
```

**Check your email**

```
git config user.email
```

**Set/change your email**

```
git config user.email "your@email.com"
```

**List/see all configuration**

```
git config --list
```

Comment: For more have a look on the official document : https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/setting-your-username-in-git

Answer (score 28):

The simplest way to know the already configured git (user name & email) is to type:

$ git config -l

That will display the previously configured information.
In order to update it, you should use the command

```
$ git config --global user.email "example@email.com"
$ git config --global user.name "your_userName"
```

And If you want to do it for a single Project use can use

```
$ git config --local user.email "example@email.com"
$ git config --local user.name "your_userName"
```

You can also check:
[1]: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Answer (score 23):

**Set Global / All projects**

first get and confirm the old values:

```
git config --global user.email
git config --global user.name
```

Output: (if git new installation then the output will show empty)

```
yourold@email.com
youroldgoodname
```

Now For set new values

```
git config --global user.email yournew@email.com
git config --global user.name yournewgoodname
```

**For current workspace or project** 
just remove --global from all above commands/lines

Answer (score 11):

Add my two cents here. If you want to get user.name or user.email only without verbose output.

On liunx, type `git config --list | grep user.name`.

On windows, type `git config --list | findstr user.name`.

This will give you user.name only.

Comment: Why not `git config --get user.name`? Is --get a newer argument?

Comment: @KevinMurray Thanks for commenting it out. I just didn't know the existence of `--git`. Your comment could be a leaner way to get `user.name` or other attribute.

Answer (score 8):

First Check If you already have the name and email in git configuration:-

To Check,

- The username:-

  git config --global user.name
- The email

  git config --global user.email

If it is already set, and you want to change or If it is not set and you want to add the username and email in the git configuration :-

To set:-

- The Username :-

  git config --global user.name "<your_username>"
- The Email :-

  git config --global user.email "<your_email>"

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes above solutions doesn't work in macbook to get username n password.

IDK why?, here i got another solution.

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain get
host=github.com
protocol=https

this will revert username and password
```

Answer (score 3):

To view git configuration type -

```
git config --list
```

To change username globally type -

```
git config --global user.name "your_name"
```

To change email globally type -

```
git config --global user.email "your_email"
```

Answer (score 0):

All good discussion here. Just want to add one point here: in many tool/app, there is a concept of user id to uniquely identify a user. The user id is usually a single word (with no embedded space), or in some cases an email address. So I came to this topic with the question: does git has another field called user id? If not, what does git uses as a unique way to identify a user?

So far, from reading the answers here, and searching through the web, I cannot find any mention of user id in git.
a. So I have to conclude that there is no such field as user id.
b. User name is unlikely to be a good candidate, as folks can have the same name, and the name is free form.
c. Then the only remaining logical choice is the email address, or email address + user name?

Indeed, one can see both from the git log of say xgboost source code:

```
commit 5c2d7a18c92b445ba897d4b0b4859508ae720883 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Jiaming Yuan <jm.yuan@outlook.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 15 14:08:26 2021 +0800

    Parallel model dump for trees. (#7040)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the settings of the user, global, core using the command `git config global -e`

Answer (score -4):

To change username globally type -

```
git config --global user.name "your_name"
```

To change email globally type -

```
git config --global user.email "your_email"
```

To change username locally type -

```
git config --local user.name "your_name"
```

To change email locally type -

```
git config --local user.email "your_email"
```

Comment: Doesn't answer OPs question