# Where does my local machine obtain my user name when doing a git push?

Tags: git, github, devops, zsh

This is a nuanced question in that I know how git config works as seen in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941346/how-to-know-the-git-username-and-email-saved-during-configuration).  This username is set correctly in .gitconfig and  correctly shows up on my `git commits`.

However .gitgconfig has nothing to do with this question.

This is because when I do a `git push` I get

> < /Users/c/top/arc > git push jon-arc main ERROR: Permission to
> jon-link-jon/arc.git denied to gui_user_name.

gui_user_name is my username as set in the GUI, that is on the server side on github.com.  It is the username you can see on a public github page as folows:

https://github.com/gui_user_name

How is my local machine pulling this up and not using the user name I have setup in my .gitconfig and that I can see being used in my git commits.

How can I adjust this?

The repository was setup using `git init` and then adding the remote using `git remote add shortname ssh_link`

Comment: The error message containing gui_user_name is sent by the server which authenticates you via the ssh key associated with your github account.

Comment: @Lee - that makes the most sense as gui_user_name shows up nowhere in my config files.  I created my SSK key pair on my local machine.  So I still don't get how it is pulling it off the github server.

Comment: @Gino - per my question, I verified that gui_user_name is nowhere in my .gitconfig files, similarly per my question, my commits are showing the correct name.

Comment: Have you added the public key to your github account? That is how you authenticate to github over ssh. See `settings -> SSH and GPG keys`

Comment: Of course ... I added the public key.  I guess I need to know how github ties my public / private key to my username.  I have two github accounts, each with their own public / private key pair.  I learned earlier a public key can not be used for two accounts, that is why I have two pairs ... one for each account.

Comment: It is not coming from the remote server, it is coming somewhere from the local public/private key pair.  It must of somehow injected that information into the .ssh directory.  I know this b.c. I am now using a repo created on account1 with public/private key created on account 1 and it still thinks I am account2.

Comment: What user is displayed if you run `ssh git@github.com`? If you increase the verbosity it should log which public key is being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Note that this applies only to *ssh* URLs, pushing to github or other sites that use the github trick (many do).**

> Where does my local machine obtain my user name when doing a git push? ... on github.com

It doesn't.  Your *local* machine **does not supply the user name**.<sup>1</sup>  What your machine supplies to GitHub—and they then use—is a *public key*.  More precisely, your local machine supplies *at least one, and perhaps many*, public keys; at least one of them must be *registered* at GitHub, and the *first* one that is *registered, received, and working* provides to GitHub the user name.

Note that for a public key to work, it must be registered in the first place, so that phrase has some redundant parts.  It's still worth thinking about though.  The process that ssh uses goes like this:

- You run—or Git runs—`ssh options user@host command` or similar: you can leave out the `user@` part to imply that ssh should use the `User` configured in `.ssh/config`, or use your machine's user name, as the user name provided to the other machine.  Since GitHub requires a literal `git` here, well, see footnote 1.  The *`command`* part can be empty to imply that you'd like an interactive shell, but since GitHub demand a non-empty command that must be one of the allowed Git commands, that too is irrelevant.  The *`options`* part can include `-i` options; it's possible to pass these through from Git, but not usually the way to go (see below).
- Ssh resolves the host to an IP address and tries to dial that "phone number".  Whoever answers requires some boilerplate protocol to set up acceptable key exchange algorithms and the like, which ssh supplies based on your ssh version and some configuration options.  They (in this case GitHub) then provide their security fingerprint and other items so that ssh can verify that they are indeed who they claim to be (via `.ssh/known_hosts`).  Then the dance begins:
- For each *identity* that ssh can offer to that host—the list of identities depends on both your ssh agent, if you have one running, and your `.ssh/config` and any `-i` options—your ssh will read the key-pair.  It will offer the public key to them (GitHub).  They will use that to encrypt a random string and send your ssh the encrypted data.  Your ssh is then expected to decrypt this data and provide the original data back to them.

When your ssh is able to send back the original data, this proves that you hold the private key of that key-pair.  That in turn proves that you are the person that the *public* key has, in the giant table over on GitHub of "this public key is Fred's, this one is Bob's, this one is Ramesh's, this one is Ilya's..."

**That is who you are.**  You claimed *indirectly* to be that person, by offering that key and then successfully decrypting something.

> I have two github accounts, each with their own public / private key pair. I learned earlier a public key can not be used for two accounts, that is why I have two pairs ... one for each account.

This is the critical bit that you left out of the original question.  **Because you have *two* keys, and *both work*, you must *carefully select which one you present*—or present *first*—to GitHub.**  It is easiest to select which one you present.

In your `.ssh/cofig` file, you can list a number of fake-or-real host names and corresponding information.  By using *fake* host names—`gh-work` and `gh-home` for instance—it's easy to get your ssh to offer *only* the work public key, or *only* the home public key.  These are probably best shown by example.  Here's a variant of what I have on my mac:

```
Host gh-work
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id.github.work.pub

Host gh-home
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id.github.home.pub
```

This means if I run `ssh gh-work`, I'll have ssh offer, to GitHub, *only* the "work usage" key.  If I run `ssh gh-home`, I'll have ssh present only the "home usage" key.

Using the `-i` flag, you can set the *first* key you'll offer.  But using the `IdentitiesOnly yes` and `IdentityFile` lines, you can set the *only* key—or keys—you'll offer: the ones listed in the `IdentityFile` lines for that `Host`, in the order they are listed.  (However, any `-i` option key does get inserted before these, even with the `IdentitiesOnly yes`, on at least some ssh implementations.  Multiple `-i` options seem to insert all the keys in that order.)

I've found that some ssh implementations require the private key file to be listed; the macOS one (with the agent running, which is a nice side effect of macOS login) allows the public key to be listed, and that's what I use on macOS and in this example.  It should not hurt to list the private key file (ssh *should* always do the right thing) but out of general paranoia I prefer to list the public one if that works, and only switch to listing the private one if I have to.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, you must get your local machine to supply the user name `git`.  But since this is a required constant, we can ignore it here.